# SPServices new item return expanded user information

Tags: 2013, spservices, caml

I'm creating new discussion in a list using SPServices, like this:

```
$().SPServices({ 
  operation: "UpdateListItems", 
  batchCmd: "New", 
  listName: discListName,
  updates: "<Batch OnError='Continue' >" + 
                "<Method ID='1' Cmd='New'>" + 
                    "<Field Name='ContentType'>Discussion</Field>" + 
                    "<Field Name='FSObjType'>1</Field>" + 
                    "<Field Name='Body'>" + msgBody + "</Field>" + 
                "</Method>" + 
            "</Batch>" 
});
```

It returns an item that includes all the info about the newly created item like ID number and author. But the author is just the name and I would like to get the expanded user information. With a query I can add this to the query.

```
CAMLQueryOptions: "<QueryOptions>" +
                      "<ExpandUserField>True</ExpandUserField>" +
                  "</QueryOptions>"
```

I'm not sure how I can add that to the update or if that is even possible.

[Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems.aspx) talks about the xmldata fragment that is returned, but doesn't mention if it is possible to get expanded user data. Any ideas?